# Insert multiple Scrapy data into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, insert, scrapy

This is my python code to crawling news data from https://bpbd.jatengprov.go.id/category/laporan-bencana/'

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
class BepeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'bepe'
allowed_domains = ['bpbd.jatengprov.go.id']
start_urls = ['https://bpbd.jatengprov.go.id/category/laporan-bencana/']
COUNT_MAX = 100
count = 0

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.post'):
        item = {
            'judul': quote.css('h2.post-title > a::text').extract_first(), 
            'teks': quote.css('div.entrytext > p::text').extract_first(), 
            'tag': quote.css('div.up-bottom-border > p.postmetadata > a::text').extract(),
        }
        yield item
        self.count = self.count + 1
        #following pagination link
        next_page_url = response.css('div.alignright > a::attr(href)').extract_first() #dapatkan link untuk selanjutnya

    if (self.count < self.COUNT_MAX):
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Is there any way to INSERT my crawling data into mysql with such array like this?

```
item = {
        'judul': quote.css('h2.post-title > a::text').extract_first(), 
        'teks': quote.css('div.entrytext > p::text').extract_first(), 
        'tag': quote.css('div.up-bottom-border > p.postmetadata > a::text').extract(),
    }
```

I have tried code below but it couldnt insert any data

```
        conn = Connection()
        mycursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = "insert into berita(judul, isi, tag) values(%s, %s, %s)"

        item = {
            'judul': quote.css('h2.post-title > a::text').extract_first(), 
            'teks': quote.css('div.entrytext > p::text').extract_first(), 
            'tag': quote.css('div.up-bottom-border > p.postmetadata > a::text').extract(),
        }
        val=(item['judul'], item['teks'], item['tag'])
        mycursor.execute(sql,val)
        conn.commit()
```

Sorry for my bad english and I hope anybody expert in python could help me

Comment: can you edit you question in order to explain better your problem? If you fix your english will also be nice...

Comment: I have done edit my question, is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks, downvote removed

Answer (score 0):

After some googling and read Q&A I found the way to insert list (multiple array as I said before).

Basically I follow scrapy tutorial from youtube and the lesson not come this way to query the data into mysql. And after I able to crawling the data I need to insert the data

The first thing we have to know what our data type first so I found my data type is list not array. Then this is my code that not found in the youtube scrapy tutorial

```
item1 = quote.css('h2.post-title > a::text').extract_first()
item2 = quote.css('div.entrytext > p::text').extract_first()        
item3 = quote.css('div.up-bottom-border > p.postmetadata > a::text').extract()
items3 = ', '.join(item3)
```

then the query is below

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO berita (judul, isi, tag) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (item1, item2, items3))
```

Hopefully it can help