# INSERT scrapy data after check no row insert before

Tags: python, mysql, insert, scrapy, mamp

After I learnt to crawling and able to insert data to mysql

[Insert multiple Scrapy data into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629498/insert-multiple-scrapy-data-into-mysql)

I found another problem when I insert several crawling data my data in mysql become big because there are too many redundant data (duplicate data)

I tried to make INSERT with WHERE NOT EXIST condition like I did in php but not work ni python

```
item1 = quote.css('h2.post-title > a::text').extract_first()
item2 = quote.css('div.entrytext > p::text').extract_first()
item3 = quote.css('div.up-bottom-border > p.postmetadata > 
a::text').extract()
items3 = ', '.join(item3)
```

This is my sql

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO berita (judul, isi, tag) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT judul FROM berita WHERE judul like '%s')", (item1, item2, items3, item1))
```

I hope somebody help me since the error keep say

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT judul FROM berita WHERE judul like ''Tanah Longsor di K' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is about duplicate quotes. You are getting that because you have added your own `'` quotes for the last variable in the query string. Those quotes get added automatically, so remove them:

`WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT judul FROM berita WHERE judul like %s)`